# Can appositives be composed of adjectives?

Tags: punctuation, appositives

I’ve been reading a bit about [apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), and all the examples seem to be revolving around noun phrases. I’m wondering if adjectives can also form appositives.

Consider, for instance, the following two sentences:

> This scenario could easily lead to a system that is too conservative, overdesigned.
>
> The predictions delivered by these techniques are coarse, aggregate.

Assuming that *too conservative* means *overdesigned*, and that *coarse* means *aggregate*, are these two constructions legitimate appositives?

In addition, I’m interested in other ways of phrasing and punctuating the above sentences. Specifically, is it grammatical to write as follows?

1. This scenario could easily lead to a system that is too conservative, or overdesigned.
2. This scenario could easily lead to a system that is too conservative—or overdesigned.

I suppose that, if I leave out the comma and the em dash as shown below, the meaning of the sentence will change, which also needs a confirmation.

3. This scenario could easily lead to a system that is too conservative or overdesigned.

If “A, B”, “A, or B”, and “A—B” at the end of sentences are grammatical, why is it legitimate to write like this? What is the explanation? How are these three constructions called?

Comment: No. Appositives are noun phrases, and nothing else.

Comment: @BillJ, does it mean that all my sentences are ungrammatical?

Comment: No, they are OK. It's just that they are no appositives present.

Comment: @BillJ, I’d like to be able to explain/justify what I do when I write “too conservative, overdesigned” or “too conservative, or overdesigned” or “too conservative—or overdesigned”. How are they called, and how can they be explained from the standpoint of grammar?

Comment: If the adjective is joined to another with a coordinator like "or", the two adjectives are said to form a coordination. So in an example like "I always feel tired or listless", we would say that "tired or listless" is a coordination of two adjective phrases functioning  as complement of "feel". If  the coordinator is omitted, we would probably still call it a coordination.

Comment: @BillJ, I think I understand how coordinators work in general, and I’m not asking about “A or B” but rather about “A, B”, “A, or B”, and “A—B” at the end of sentences. Why is it legitimate to write like that? How are these three constructions called?

Comment: The name you are looking for is [*asyndetic coordination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton), not apposition.

Comment: @BillJ, what about the adjective "special" in "Besides these essential adverbials... there are also specific adverbials that describe other, special, kinds of qualifications."? "Special" seems to me to be in apposition with "other" there; but is it an example of coordination too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dictionaries, such as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apposition), define "apposition" solely in terms of nouns or "noun equivalents".  Other sources give a vaguer definition: [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apposition) refers to "a relationship between two or more words or phrases in which the two units are grammatically parallel and have the same referent".  The full OED defines "apposition" broadly before giving a narrower, more specific definition:

> *Grammar.* The placing of a word beside, or in syntactic parallelism with, another; spec. the addition of one substantive to another, or to a noun clause, as an attribute or complement; the position of the substantive so added.

In Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech and Svartvik, *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Longman, 1985), it is contended that relations between adjectives can be "appositive-like" but that the term "apposition" should be reserved for noun phrases.  In section 17.74, the authors write:

> Appositive-like relations exist also between other units than noun phrase, such as clauses [4], predications [5], and adjectives [6].
>
> *Although she was reluctant, although she felt an understandable hesitation, she eventually agreed.* [4]
>
> *They had summoned help - called the police and fire brigade.* [5]
>
> *She is better, very much better, than she used to be.* [6]
>
> However, to talk about apposition of units other than noun phrases makes the concept of apposition too weak.  Such apposition-like constructions will be treated as exceptional.

Huddleston & Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, also reserves the term "apposition" for noun phrases.

On the other hand, Otto Jespersen (*Essentials of English Grammar*) uses a much broader definition to "apposition".  Jespersen states, for example, that "participles are very often placed in apposition, either after or before the word they qualify".  His examples include:

> He came back, utterly exhausted, from his long ride.
>
> She went out, having first locked the drawer carefully.

But *Essentials* was published in 1933.  I feel pretty sure that Huddleston & Pullum and Quirk et al. are more representative of today's consensus.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I wonder what the implications of this for my sentences (mainly “A, B” but also “A, or B” and “A—B”) are. I understand that we probably shouldn’t label them as “apposition,” but do they fall into some other category? If they cannot be explained, I suppose they are ungrammatical.

Comment: You're misreading the Jespersen there, I think. "In apposition" is just being used as an everyday term to mean "next to each other". He is not saying that participle phrases are appositions! _

Comment: @Araucaria That's conceivable, I suppose, but (a) the OED definition (even of the grammatical sense) deliberately includes non-nouns, and (b) the bit I quoted from Jespersen is in a section called "Apposition. Extraposition" and is in the paragraph immediately following the one that discusses apposition of nouns.

Comment: Can you tell me whether the word "special" in the following sentence is an appositive adjective too; or is it some other type: "Besides these *essential* adverbials... there are also *specific* adverbials that describe other, special, kinds of qualifications..."? By now I have come across similar sentences many times that have a series of adjectives before a noun but the last adjective in the series is set off by commas on **both** sides, not just the left as is common, and so seems to be a parenthetical. But I haven't found a mention of *parenthetical* adjectives anywhere, and so am. . .

Comment: ... wondering whether "appositive adjectives" is what they come under too.

Answer (score 1):

OP writes:

**I’m interested in other ways of phrasing and punctuating the ... sentences.**

> This scenario could easily lead to a system that is too conservative,
>   overdesigned.
>
> The predictions delivered by these techniques are coarse, aggregate.

I don't see **conservative** as being synonymous with **overdesigned**, and would therefore link these adjectives with AND or OR:

> This scenario could easily lead to a system that is overdesigned and too conservative.
>
> This scenario could easily lead to a system that is either overdesigned or too conservative.

I deal frequently with aggregated data but I wouldn't know what an *aggregate prediction* was exactly:

> The predictions delivered by these techniques are **coarse, aggregate**.

Also, asyndeton is better suited to prose that seeks to *evoke* than it is to prose that seeks to *explain*.

Perhaps you might want to say what these techniques *cannot* do:

> These techniques cannot deliver precise predictions.